# Reset default graph upon exiting tf.Session() in unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow, testing, pytest

- At the end of each unit tests, I call `tf.reset_default_graph()` to clear the default graph.
- However, when a unit test fails, the graph doesn't get cleared. That makes the next unit test fails as well.

How to clear a graph upon exiting the `tf.Session()` context?

Example (pytest):

```
import tensorflow as tf


def test_1():
    x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(4 / 0)
        print(sess.run(x))


def test_2():
    x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(sess.run(x))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to use the tools `pytest` offers:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def reset():
    yield
    tf.reset_default_graph()
```

The fixture will be automatically invoked before and after each test (flag `autouse`), code before/after `yield` is executed before/after test. This way the tests from your question will work without any modification and you follow the DRY principle, refusing to write duplicated code in each test. Another example:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def init_graph():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        yield
```

will create a new graph for each test before the test executes.

Fixtures in `pytest` are very powerful and can fully eliminate code repetitions when used properly. For example, the tests from your question are equivalent to:

```
@pytest.fixture
def x():
    return tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)


@pytest.fixture
def session(x):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        yield sess


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def init_graph():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        yield


def test_1(session, x):
    print(4 / 0)
    print(session.run(x))


def test_2(session, x):
    print(session.run(x))
```

If you want to learn more, start with [pytest fixtures: explicit, modular, scalable](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```py
import tensorflow as tf


def test_1():
    G = tf.Graph()
    with G.as_default():
        x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.initializers.global_variables())
            print(sess.run(x))
            print(4 / 0)


def test_2():
    G = tf.Graph()
    with G.as_default():
        x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.initializers.global_variables())
            print(sess.run(x))
```

Comment: Then, one easy solution would just be a try / except: and in the except, you reset the graph and then you raise an error. Not very pretty though

Comment: my bad, your solution actually works. I forget to initialize the variables.

Comment: Yes, I was just trying and I couldnt even make test_2 work. Great then!

Answer (score 2):

A direct solution is to use the `try` ... `finally` clause (actually it may be better to put the clause in the code that runs the unit tests rather than in the unit tests directly):

```
def test_1():
    x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)
    try:
       with tf.Session() as sess:
           sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
           print(4 / 0)
           print(sess.run(x))
    finally:
       tf.reset_default_graph()


def test_2():
    x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)
    try:
        with tf.Session() as sess:
           sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            print(sess.run(x))
    finally:
        tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Another clean solution is to use one graph for each unit test as shown in the previous answer. Here is an alternative solution based on this idea with a slightly simplified syntax:

```
def test_1():
    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
        x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(4 / 0)
        print(sess.run(x))


def test_2():
    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
        x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=1)

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(sess.run(x))
```

Similarly to the first solution, the `with` statement can also be put around the code that runs the unit tests rather than being repeated in every unit test.

Comment: the 2nd method is a bit cleaner. But it needs to indent a lot of things in the test.

Comment: As I explained at the end of the answer, you can put `with tf.Graph().as_default()` in the code that runs the tests and keep `test_1` and `test_2` methods unchanged.